# A CSS string – select everything up to third comma

Tags: javascript, regex, string, scriptaculous

I'm writing a custom highlight animation with Scriptaculous that includes a CSS3 glow. I get the box-shadow style and need to split it at the rgba alpha value, then vary that value to get the shadow to fade.

```
$('fresh').style.MozBoxShadow
```

would return

```
0 0 20px rgba(163, 238, 71, 1.0)
```

`1.0` is the alpha value. I need to split it so that I can set:

```
$('fresh').style.MozBoxShadow = everythingBeforeAlphaValue + anAlphaValueIVaryWithJS + ')';
```

All the numbers can be any number of digits long, so I can't use `substring` (and that's all I really know :) ). Can you help?

Answer (score 2):

```
var mozBoxShadow = $('fresh').style.MozBoxShadow;
var everythingBeforeAlphaValue = /.*?rgba\((?:\d*,\s*){3}/.exec(mozBoxShadow)[0];
```

Answer (score 2):

Well, you can still use `substring`, because you can know the [`lastIndexOf(',')`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Objects/String/lastIndexOf), for example:

```
var str = "0 0 20px rgba(163, 238, 71, 1.0)";

var everythingBeforeAlphaValue  = str.substring(0, str.lastIndexOf(',') + 1);
// "0 0 20px rgba(163, 238, 71,"
// ...
```

Answer (score 1):

This would be better and cleaner done programmatically, without parsing a string.

If I understand the [logic](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/CSS/-moz-box-shadow) right, you should be able to reach the colour directly via

```
$('fresh').style.MozBoxShadowColor
```

That'll save you one part of it.

I'm also quite sure it is possible to access the "alpha" component of a colour programmatically, but I don't know how.

Comment: You'd think so, but it comes back undefined. I guess that's why they're still under vendor specific prefixes.

Comment: Ah crap. All right. And when I Google it, what is the only thing that comes up? This very answer. Who are SO's bosses sleeping with at Google? :)